# What part of speech is "many" in "...she has read as many as possible of the books and articles..."?

Tags: grammar, usage

From Thompson, Geoff. (1994). Collins Cobuild English Guides: Reporting. p. 179.

> The author does this by showing that she has read as **many** as possible
> **of** the books and articles that have already been written about the
> subject.

I can understand the meaning of this sentence,but fail to take the grammatical usage of "as many as possible" and the following "of".

If "many" is an adjective, how to take the following "of"?

If "many" is a pronoun, how to take the "as" ahead? As I know, the first "as" is an adverb,so can not modify a pronoun.

Or,"as many as possible" being an adverbial modifies "read of":

> The author does this by showing that she has read **[as many as
> possible]** of the books and articles that have already been written
> about the subject. ?

Comment: "Many" is classed as a **determinative**. Here, it's functioning as a 'fused determiner head', understood as "many books and articles".

Comment: @BillJ But,how to take the following "of"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that "of books and articles" is a complement of "many" which has been postposed because of its length/weight + relative clause. So the adverb "as" is modifying the NP "many [of books and articles]' which complement has been moved at the end.

Alternative sentence:

"The author does this by showing that she has read as [many of the books and articles that have already been written about the subject] as possible."

Comment: I've removed some of the chat.  An answer is an answer, you don't need to apologise for it.

Comment: Thanks! That sounds encouraging to me.

Comment: The OP’s title asks which part of speech it is.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum Check user BillJ's comment for the POS.